# How can I store the number of elements in a tkinter frame as an integer?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a conditional statement that throws an error to the user if there aren't any widgets in the frame.

I attempted this:

```
    if frame.winfo_children() < 1:
      errorMessage = tk.Label(master, text='Error. No file selected', fg='#FF0000')
      canvas.create_window(200, 50, window=errorMessage)
```

However, this doesn't work due to the fact that ternary operators don't support comparisons between lists and integers. How can I just get the number of widgets in the frame as an `int` type?

Comment: Why are you using a `while` instead of an `if` statement?

Comment: Good point. I'm new to buttons so if the function runs every time the button is clicked, I have no need for a ```while``` statement. That probably would've caused me an error down the line. Appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, it would have caused a problem — because it creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if len(frame.winfo_children()) < 1:` instead.